# Laravel one to many polymorphic - one (model) to many (many types of models)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5.7

So, i've been searching for a long time now, none of the answers here match this query.

I have a channel, and each channel can have multiple types of streams, 
each type is a different model. 
each stream can only belong to one channel.
[Schema?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7le7.png)

So its a one to many relationship, one channel has many streams of different type but each stream belongs to only one channel.

I know polymorphic relationship is required to assert which stream model it is but, how on earth do i link the channel to each stream?

I can have `channel_id` field at each of the stream models tables, but then how would i get them all via the channel model? well, here's where the polymorphic relationship is required, but how it applied?
the only way i can think of is a pivot table that will contain `channel_id, stream_id, stream_type.`
[Schema?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wVTU.png)
However, this makes it a many to many relationship now doesn't it?! 
and how would i access it? `$channel->stream->streamable` or even worst, how would i set it? save streamable to the Stream and attach Stream to Channel and ?

Any ideas how's best to implement such thing?

Comment: If `each type is a different model` then put `channel_id`  as FK in each model that's it!

Comment: @Iftikharuddin "I can have channel_id field at each of the stream models tables, but then how would i get them all via the channel model?"
I would have to create a method for each model type which is exactly what i don't want to do. i want to call $channel->streams and get a collection of all the stream of any type.
as well as just attach them as simply as $channel->streams()->attach($someModelInstance)

Comment: Laravel doesn't offer a way to implement a `streams` relationship, with or without a pivot table. For the retrieving part, you can use a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52877724